# Friendly ID in a rails controller concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, friendly-id

i am beginning to create a module that has shared functionality in the controllers of my rails app. I am trying to include a record find in another controller that requires that record. I use friendly id to slug instances of a corp_page, trying to find the corp_pages record the controllers gives me this error,

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound at /admin/corporate_pages/home/corporate_panels
Couldn't find CorporatePage without an ID
```

The code,

```
module CorporateConcern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_filter :get_corp_page
    before_filter :get_corp_panel
  end

  def get_corp_page
    @corp_page = CorporatePage.friendly.find(params[:id])
  end

  def get_corp_panel
    @corp_panel = CorporatePanel.where(id: params[:id]).first
  end
end

class Admin::CorporatePanelsController < AdminController
  include CorporateConcern
  ......
end

class Admin::CorporatePagesController < AdminController
  include CorporateConcern
end
```

thanks in advance

Comment: How can params[:id] be simultaneously the id of a CorporatePanel and the slug (or id) for a CorporatePage?